# Can anybody solve the equation $a.2^{\sin^2 x} + a.2^{-\sin^2 x} - 2 = 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, trigonometry

The equation : $a.2^{\sin^2 x} + a.2^{-\sin^2 x} - 2 = 0$ has equal roots if and only if ***a*** lies in the interval
(a) $\left(0, \frac{\pi}{3}\right)$
(b) $\left(\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$
(c) $\left(\frac{\pi}{3},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$
(d) $\left(0, \frac{\pi}{4}\right)$

Comment: is this $$a\cdot 2^{\sin^2(x)}+a\cdot 2^{-\sin^2(x)}-2=0$$?

Comment: Yes, someone can solve it.  But in this forum, you need to show your own work before expecting comments from us.

Comment: what do we know about $a$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $t=2^{\sin^2 x}$ so $ 1 \leq t \leq 2$ because $0\leq \sin^2 x \leq 1$, on the other hand $a t+\frac{a}{t}=2$

Multiply by $t$ since $t\not=0$ you will get $a t^2 -2t +a=0$ solving for $t$ using the quadratic equation one gets that $t=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-a^2}}{a}$ and $t=\frac{1+\sqrt{1-a^2}}{a}$

Since $1\leq t \leq 2$ we can bound the solutions to get that $1 \leq \frac{1-\sqrt{1-a^2}}{a} \leq 2$ and $1 \leq \frac{1+\sqrt{1-a^2}}{a} \leq 2$

solving for $a$ , we arrive at $\frac{4}{5} \leq a \leq 1$.

So the right interval is (b) $(\frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{\pi}{2})$.

Edit : i am not sure about the "if and only if" since there is some values taking from any interval which will give complex solution for $x$.

Comment: How did you arrive at $a \in \bigg( \dfrac{\pi}4, \dfrac \pi 2\bigg)$ from $ \dfrac 45 \le a \le 1$ ? If $a = 1.5$ it is in your interval and it is more than $1$.

Comment: @A---B this what i mentioned in the Edit , i said its contained in the interval but the sentence "if and only if" is a problematic because then all the intervals not the correct answer.

Comment: An easier way to get that same inequality would be, $$$$
Let $y = \sin^2 x$.

Then, $a(2^y + 2^{-y}) = 2$


$$\dfrac{e^{y\ln 2} + e^{-y\ln 2} }{2} = \dfrac1a$$


$$\cosh(y\ln 2) = \dfrac1a$$

Since $$0 \le y\ln2 \le \ln 2 \implies1 \le \cosh(y \ln 2) \le \dfrac54$$

Therefore $$1 \le \dfrac 1a \le \dfrac54$$.

Answer (score 2):

$$a.2^{\sin^2 x} + a.2^{-\sin^2 x} - 2 = 0$$ setting
$X= 2^{\sin^2 x}$ then the equation become,

$$aX^2+\frac{a}{X }-2 = 0 \Longleftrightarrow X^2-2X +a = 0$$
which posses a soltion iff $|a|\le 1$ since $$\Delta =  4(1-a^2)$$

in that case. 
the solutions are

$$ X= \frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-a^2}}{a}$$

That is $$ 2^{\sin^2 x} = \frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-a^2}}{a}$$

> First Constraint $$\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-a^2}}{a}>0$$ since 
>   $ 2^{\sin^2 x}>0$.

With this we have
$$ \sin ^2x = \log_2\left( \frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-a^2}}{a}\right)$$

> Second Constraint 
>   $$ 0\le \log_2\left( \frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-a^2}}{a}\right)\le 1$$
>   since $0\le\sin ^2x\le1.$

**The study of the first and the second constraint lead to required range for $a$ and it is left to OP since it will be very long and should not be too difficult**